# Where does the igmp version get set in RedHat 7

Tags: redhat, igmp, multicasting

Is there a different location/method to set the default igmp version for multicast on a RedHat 7 server other than using the force parameter  (net.ipv4.conf.eth0.force_igmp_version = 0 ) in sysctl.conf or sysctl.d etc. In the example above the 0 implies that there is a default which I assume is V3. The output below has a value of V2 on eth0 but it is not set or forced anywhere that I can find.

```
Idx Device    : Count Querier   Group    Users Timer    Reporter
    1   lo        :     1      V3
                    010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
    2   eth0      :     2      V2 
                    0A0707E7     1 0:00000000       1
                    010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
    3   eth1      :     1      V3
                    010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
    4   eth2      :     1      V3
                    010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
```

Any Linux expert there with an idea

Answer (score 0):

you can try net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version=2 instead of forcing it one place, force for every interface.